# Extract all values from JSON

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino

**I have some data that looks like this:**

| Data From Other Columns | JSON Data |
| --- | --- |
| Data 1 | JSON 1 |
| Data 2 | JSON 2 |

**The JSON data looks like this:**

```
{
    "status": "x"
    ,"campaigns": [
        {"channel": "channel_1", "name": "sample_1"}
        ,{"channel": "channel_2", "name": "sample2"}
        ,{"channel": "channel_3", "name": "sample_3"}
    ]
 }
```

**I need to create a query that gives me 1 row for every channel.**
Using `JSON_QUERY()` only gives me an output if the campaign has only 1 channel. In the example above, `JSON_QUERY()` would fail because there are 3 channels in the campaign.

```
SELECT
    normal_data
    ,json_array
    ,json_query(
        json_array
        ,'lax $.campaigns.channel'
     ) AS test
FROM test
```

However, this only gets me the instances with only ONE channel and produces an error otherwise. I'd need to get every instance of a channel and name.

**My expected output is:**

| Normal Data From Other Columns | Channel | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data_1 | channel_1 | sample_1 |
| data_1 | channel_2 | sample_2 |
| data_1 | channel_3 | sample_3 |
| data_2 | channel_1 | sample_1 |
| data_2 | channel_2 | sample_2 |
| data_2 | channel_2 | sample_3 |

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please update your question to show the result you are trying to achieve, based on your source data, and the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: @EmilioSilva there is no `OPENJSON` function in Trino/Presto.

Comment: @NickW - I've updated the question with my expected output and attempted SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would just use the `json_extract` function with some casting (to array) and unnesting. For example:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (json_col) as (values ('{
    "status": "x","campaigns": [
        {"channel": "channel_1", "name": "sample_1"}
        ,{"channel": "channel_2", "name": "sample2"}
        ,{"channel": "channel_3", "name": "sample_3"}
    ]
 }'))

-- query
select m['channel'] channel,
       m['name']    name
from dataset
, unnest(
    -- or array(map(varchar, json))
    cast(json_extract(json_parse(json_col), '$.campaigns') as array(map(varchar, varchar))) 
  ) as t(m);
```

Output:

| channel | name |
| --- | --- |
| channel_1 | sample_1 |
| channel_2 | sample2 |
| channel_3 | sample_3 |

Comment: Thank you! This got me what I needed. 
I can add other data from other columns in my dataset as well which is also what I needed. 

Quick questions to help with my learning:
- What's behind the naming convention of t(m)?
- The m['json_column_name'] references the key in the map, correct?

Comment: @MiguelBarrientos _"What's behind the naming convention of `t(m)`"_ - nothing in particular TBH, `t` was used in some `unnest`  examples I have seen online and `m` is "short" for `map`. _"The `m['json_column_name']` references the key in the map, correct?"_ - yes.